# iOS Minimum OS Requirements for my Binary ignoring settings

Tags: ios, xcode, deployment, connect

In xcode 4, I have my "iOS Deployment Target" set to 4.0 for both my project and my target app. When I upload it and then check the binary details in iTunes connect, it shows up with a Minimum OS Requirements as 4.3 instead of 4.0.

WHY!?

[image: in xcode]
[image: in itunes connect]

---

Comment: Is this for an update or a new app?

Comment: New app. It looks like I have my settings right for debug/release too...
[http://i.imgur.com/31ezv.png](screen shot)

Answer (score 1):

Ah - the answer was simply "patience"! I guess they don't update the binary details when you upload a new one, it took about 12 hours for the details to refresh and my new (correct) Minimum OS Requirements number to appear.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you're making these changes for the "Release" and not just the "Debug" setting. Also, it may help to do a Build/Clean All Targets followed by manually deleting the Build/ directory, and then do Build/Build and Archive.

Comment: How do I switch settings between release/debug?

Comment: Depends on the version of Xcode you're using. Mine looks different from your screenshots, so I'm not sure in your case.

Comment: Using xcode 4.0 here, most of the stuff I've found through google on this issue seem to have some options that aren't there any more or that I can't seem to find with this version of xcode...